# Aggregations with searchkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, searchkick

I'm trying to get this Aggregations thing working with my search results page.

I'm struggling with this at the moment. So far i do not know what to put into my view.

I have this in my controller,

```
@events = Event.search params[:search], suggest: true, partial: true, misspellings: {distance: 2}, aggs: [:eventname, :type]
```

I don't know what to put in the view, I cant seem to find any help for this.

Also I would like to put a date filter on, So any events that are within a certain date range it would only show these.

Any help would be much appreciated

Sam

Answer (score 0):

To get searched events

```
@events.to_a
```

To get events count

```
@events.count
```

To get aggregation result

```
@events.aggs
```